# how to store bcrypt hashpw result in db correctly?

Tags: postgresql, bcrypt

I am in the process of creating a login system.
I use `python flask` and as database the `Prostgresql`.

I think I just store the hash value wrong.
I have saved it as vachar 255 so far

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import bcrypt
import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:PostGreSQL_13@localhost/test'
sql = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/register', methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')
        hash_password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())

        t_host = 'localhost'
        t_port = "5432"
        t_dbname = "test"
        t_user = "postgres"
        t_pw = "password"

        db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=t_host, port=t_port, dbname=t_dbname, user=t_user, password=t_pw)
        db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

        db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (UserName,UserEmail,UserPassword) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",(name,email,hash_password,))
        db_conn.commit()

        session['name'] = name
        session['email'] = email
        return redirect(url_for("home"))



@app.route('/login', methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')

        t_host = 'localhost'
        t_port = "5432"
        t_dbname = "test"
        t_user = "postgres"
        t_pw = "password"

        db_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=t_host, port=t_port, dbname=t_dbname, user=t_user, password=t_pw)
        db_cursor = db_conn.cursor()

        db_cursor.execute("SELECT username, useremail, userpassword FROM users WHERE useremail=%s",(email,))

        user = db_cursor.fetchone()
        db_conn.close()

        if len(user) > 0:
            name = user[0]
            if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user[2].encode('utf-8')) == user[2].encode('utf-8'):
                session['name'] = user[0]
                session['email'] = user[1]
                return render_template("home.html")

        else:
            return "Versuch es doch Nochmal"
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")



@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '012#!ApaAjaBoleh)(*^%'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

the procedure I got from the Youtube video. see attachment.

I need a login system and this was recommended to me, it works pretty good.

The last one has to work somehow and if it works I would be very happy.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if my appendix with the database is right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about this language you're using, but any bcrypt implementation will output a string similar to:

> `$2a$12$ieXy2Rj/TEGqVRx0JihGFesujNFCdmlQWpUaTNvwQ0XuB3lzOcTWK`

Yes, you should store that varchar string in your database.